# Append a string when the data is sent as JSON in Laravel Controller

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What I want to do is to append the string `'string/'` when I send a JSON response.

For example:

When I send data its as a collection like so..

`return response()->json("example_json" => $datacollection)`

This would display as:

```
{
  "example_json"
   [{
      "data1": "somedata1",
      "data2": "somedata2",
      "data3": "somedata3"
   }]
}
```

**Now**, what I want to do is append a string, for example the 3rd data's variable content:

```
{
  "example_json"
   [{
      "data1": "somedata1",
      "data2": "somedata2",
      "data3": "string/somedata3"
   }]
}
```

Is there any kind of method to do this without changing the data permanently in the database? I just want to do this once or twice not change the name of the content in the database only when it is sent to, change its name.

Thankyou very much!

Comment: Is `$dataCollection` an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`?

Comment: Sorry no, so it is data from doing `$datacollection = DB::table('database')->get();`

Comment: Convert into collection first, then add your data, then again parse into JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom attribute accessor to modify the model's data on retrieval. That way you can modify it when you get the data, but it will not change it when storing data:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

E.g.

```
public function getData3Attribute($value)
{
    return 'string/'.$value;
}
```

Then when you retrieve the model it will look like this:

```
{
    "data1": "somedata1",
    "data2": "somedata2",
    "data3": "string/somedata3"
}
```

NOTE: This transformation will happen anywhere you retrieve `data3`, including PHP code. If you ONLY want to modify values when sending a JSON response, check out API resources:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

JSON resource toArray() method:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data1' => $this->data1,
        'data2' => $this->data2,
        'data3' => 'string/'.$this->data3,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! correct answer because you pointed me in the right direction! thankyou :))

Comment: Your first example was the one that I used pretty much, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use `map()` here to update the data as needed.

E.g.

```
$updatedDatacollection = $datacollection->map(function($item, $key){
    if($key == 'data3') { // or some other condition ...
        return 'string/' . $item; // append a string
    }
    return $item; // otherwise leave it unchanged
});
```

This will update the `$updatedDatacollection` but leave the database unchanged. Then you can return as JSON like you are already doing.